# Polymer Paper-Tab core-animated-pages. Fails to work when adding core-animated pages.?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Here is My [html](http://href=https://github.com/DannyBoyBroadSword/PolymerTests/blob/master/polymertest.html)
This is the most important the body:

```
      </div>
        </div>
            <div horizontal center-justified layout>
                <img src ="http://andrewhennessy.net.s3.amazonaws.com/www.drudgereport.com/i/logo9.gif"</img>
            </div>

          <core-toolbar class="medium-tall">

          <paper-icon-button id="navicon"
            icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>

          <span flex>Main</span>

          <paper-icon-button id="morebutton"
            icon="home"></paper-icon-button>

          <paper-tabs class="bottom fit" selected="0" id="tabs">
            <paper-tab onClick="stuff(0);">Top</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab onClick="stuff(1);">Left</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab onClick="stuff(2);">Center</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab onClick="stuff(3);">Right</paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
       </core-toolbar>

       <div layout horizontal center-center fit>
    <core-animated-pages  selected="0" transitions="slide-from-right">
  <section layout vertical center-center>
  <div>Single</div>
  </section>
  <section layout vertical center-center>
    <div>page</div>
  </section>
  ...
    </core-animated-pages>
  </div>
```

and my script:

```
   function change() {
     var s = document.querySelector('select');
     document.querySelector('core-animated-pages').transitions =           document.querySelector('select').options[s.selectedIndex].value;
}

function stuff(page) {
  var p = document.querySelector('core-animated-pages');
  p.selected = page;

}
```

I have made sure to import all necessary polymer elements so that is not an issue.

Every time I try I use core animated pages, the whole program stops working I need help integrating both core-animated pages and paper-tab layout.

Comment: You better include the essential parts of your html code. It results in less work for people to answer your question. (A small amount of work for you, but multiplied by a large factor in time you save others).

Comment: Okay thanks so just add that to the question or edit my original question. I appreciate your feedback!!

Comment: just edit your question with a (limited) amount of html code: a minimal (not-)working example.

Comment: Okay I've made my change I think it looks good now

Comment: Have you checked the console log on Google Chrome? Does it give you and error?